# Keras training project fails without error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Trying to do write a siamese neural network. Code gets to epoch 1 spends awhile there then just exits. No errors or exceptions shown.

I'm using fit_generator to try and randomly pair up images based on some parameters. Idea being I want to try to train a siamese network to output a feature vector where the distance between 2 vectors is low if the images are matches.

I'm on Windows x64. I installed with pip install tensorflow-gpu and installed cuda 9.0 and cudnn 7.2 . Tensorflow definitely launches as I get output from it but not sure why it's failing.

train.py

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy.random as rng
from whalegenerator import WhaleGenerator

import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.optimizers import SGD,Adam
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from keras.models import Model, Sequential, save_model, load_model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Lambda, Subtract, Dense, Flatten,MaxPooling2D

ProcessImages = True
TrainPath = '.\\processed\\train'
ProcessedPath = '.\\processed'
TrainTruthPath = '.\\train.csv'

def buildModel():
    #We are building a saimese network
    input_shape = (256,256,1)
    left = Input(input_shape)
    right = Input(input_shape)

    convnet = Sequential()
    convnet.add(Conv2D(64,(9,9),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape,kernel_initializer='random_normal',kernel_regularizer=l2(2E-4)))
    convnet.add(MaxPooling2D())
    convnet.add(Conv2D(128,(7,7),activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(2E-4),kernel_initializer='random_normal',bias_initializer='random_normal'))
    convnet.add(MaxPooling2D())
    convnet.add(Conv2D(256,(5,5),activation='relu',kernel_initializer='random_normal',kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4),bias_initializer='random_normal'))
    convnet.add(MaxPooling2D())
    convnet.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',kernel_initializer='random_normal',kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4),bias_initializer='random_normal'))
    convnet.add(Flatten())
    convnet.add(Dense(2048,activation="sigmoid",kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-3),kernel_initializer='random_normal',bias_initializer='random_normal'))

    encodedL = convnet(left)
    encodedR = convnet(right)

    subtract = Subtract()([encodedL,encodedR])
    diff = Lambda(lambda x: K.abs(x))(subtract)
    prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',bias_initializer='random_normal')(diff)
    siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left,right],output=prediction)
    run_opts = tf.RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom = True)
    siamese_net.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer=Adam(6E-5),options=run_opts,metrics=['accuracy'])
    return siamese_net 

model = buildModel()
print(model.count_params())
batch_size = 32
generator = Generator(TrainPath,TrainTruthPath,batch_size,(256,256))

try:
        result = model.fit_generator(generator=generator,epochs=100,steps_per_epoch=int(np.floor(len(generator)/batch_size)),max_queue_size=50,verbose=2,callbacks=[
                ModelCheckpoint('.\\models\\image_256.h5',save_best_only=True,monitor='accuracy')
                ])
except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
else:
        print('unkown error')

print('finished!')
```

generator

```
import os
import cv2
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.utils import Sequence

class Generator(Sequence):

    #Number of items in the group
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.imageList)/2))

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        X = [np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, 1)) for i in range(2)]
        Y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=float)

        # Generate data
        matches = 0
        matchKeys = list(self.hasMatches.items())
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            if self.batch_size - i < self.min_match and matches < self.min_match:
                id1 = random.choice(matchKeys)[0]
                images1 = self.imgGroups[id1]
                X[0][i,] = images1[random.randint(0,len(images1)-1)]
                X[1][i,] = images1[random.randint(0,len(images1)-1)]
                Y[i] = 1.0
                matches += 1
            else:
                item1 = self.imageList[random.randint(0,len(self.imageList)-1)]
                id1 = item1["Id"]
                X[0][i,] = item1["Image"]
                images1 = self.imgGroups[id1]
                if id1 != "new_whale" and len(images1) > 1 and random.random() <= 0.5: 
                    X[1][i,] = images1[random.randint(0,len(images1)-1)]
                    Y[i] = 1.0
                    matches += 1.0
                else:
                    item2 = self.imageList[random.randint(0,len(self.imageList)-1)]
                    id2 = item2["Id"]
                    X[1][i,] = item2["Image"]
                    if id1 != "new_whale" and id1 == id2:
                        Y[i] = 1.0
                        matches += 1.0
                    else:
                        Y[i] = 0.0

        return X, Y

    def __init__(self, image_path, csv, batch_size, dim):

        self.min_match = 3
        self.imgGroups = { }
        self.imageList = [ ]
        self.hasMatches = { }
        self.dim = dim
        self.df = pd.read_csv(csv)
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        for i, row in self.df.iterrows():

            _id = row["Id"]
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path,row["Image"]))

            if img is None:
                continue

            img = img[:,:,0]
            img = img.reshape((*self.dim,1))
            self.imageList.append({ "Id": _id, "Image": img })
            if not _id in self.imgGroups:
                self.imgGroups[_id] = [img]
            else:
                if _id != "new_whale":
                    self.hasMatches[_id] = True

                self.imgGroups[_id].append(img)
```

Output

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
83297857
Epoch 1/100
2018-12-21 21:31:59.191422: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-12-21 21:32:00.023587: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 980M major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.1265
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.32GiB
2018-12-21 21:32:00.035814: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-12-21 21:32:00.460105: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-12-21 21:32:00.467842: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971]      0
2018-12-21 21:32:00.473743: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N
2018-12-21 21:32:00.478649: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3039 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow is by default created to use AVX ( Advanced Vector Instructions ) instructions of a specific type. Your CPU supports AVX2 as mentioned in the output which is not used by TensorFlow.

- You can try with the Conda packages of TensorFlow, if you use Anaconda.